# Websocket request sometimes doesn't work after connection establishment

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a Node.js script which is supposed to regularly access a SailsJS application via a socket connection. Client and server run on physically different machines on different networks. The SailsJS application is proxied behind nginx.  That works in general. However, at random times, the connection is established but the first `post` request within the websocket connection never reaches its destination.

The code looks basically like this:

```
var socketIOClient = require('socket.io-client');
var sailsIOClient = require('sails.io.js');

var io = sailsIOClient(socketIOClient);
io.sails.url = 'https://foo.foo:443';
io.sails.rejectUnauthorized = false;

io.socket.on('connect', function() {

    console.log("Connected!")

    io.socket.post('/someroute', { someOptions: "foo" } ,
            function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });

});

io.socket.on('disconnect', function(){
  console.log("Disconnected!");
});

io.socket.on('connect_error',function () {
  console.log("connect_error!");
});
```

In case of a failure, simply nothing happens after `console.log("Connected!")`. Nothing appears in nginx's logs (in contrast to successful cases), the callback of `io.socket.post` never gets executed.

The most important question for me is: At which side is the problem? Client or server?

How can I debug this and narrow down the problem? Could it be a networking issue? Or something wrong the configuration, implementation or with the script itself?

Comment: Launch a wireshark session to watch what is sent / received over the ethernet line